# Why the output is always wrong?

Tags: c, android-activity

I need help with this code in C, the code needs to return the reverse path to the indicated file, but my code is returning "File not found"

This is the activity:(dontpad.com/ap9dk)

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct TipoNo {
  char info;
} TipoNo;
typedef struct TipoArv {
  char name[100];
  struct TipoArv* son;
  struct TipoArv* brother;
  struct TipoArv* dad;
} TipoArv;
// create
TipoArv* cria(char c[]) {
  TipoArv* novo = (TipoArv*)malloc(sizeof(TipoArv));
  strcpy(novo->name, c);
  novo->son = NULL;
  novo->brother = NULL;
  novo->dad = NULL;
  return novo;
}
// initialize
void inicializa(TipoArv* a) {
  char t[1025] = "\\root";
  TipoArv* raiz = cria(t);
  a->son = raiz;
  a->brother = NULL;
  a->dad = NULL;
}
// insert
void insere(TipoArv* dad, TipoArv* subarv) {
  subarv->brother = dad->son;
  dad->son = subarv;
  subarv->dad = dad;
}
// remove
void remover(TipoArv* raiz, char* arquivo) {
  if (raiz == NULL)
    return;
  TipoArv* atual = raiz->son;
  TipoArv* anterior = NULL;
  while (atual != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(atual->name, arquivo) == 0) {
      if (anterior == NULL) {
        raiz->son = atual->brother;
      }
      else {
        anterior->brother = atual->brother;
      }
      free(atual);
      return;
    }
    anterior = atual;
    atual = atual->brother;
  }

  atual = raiz->son;
  while (atual != NULL) {
    remover(atual, arquivo);
    atual = atual->brother;
  }
}
// search
TipoArv* buscar(TipoArv* raiz, char name[]) {
  if (raiz == NULL)
    return NULL;
  if (strcmp(raiz->name, name) == 0) {
    return raiz;
  }

  TipoArv* atual = raiz->son;
  while (atual != NULL) {
    TipoArv* encontrado = buscar(atual, name);
    if (encontrado != NULL) {
      return encontrado;
    }
    atual = atual->brother;
  }
  return NULL;
}
// print
int imprimir_caminho(TipoArv* raiz, char arquivo[]) {
  if (raiz == NULL)
    return 0;
  if (strcmp(raiz->name, arquivo) == 0) {

    if (raiz->son != NULL) {

      return imprimir_caminho(raiz->son, arquivo);
    }
    else {

      printf("%s", raiz->name);
      TipoArv* atual = raiz->dad;
      while (atual != NULL) {
        printf(" -> %s", atual->name);
        atual = atual->dad;
      }
      printf("\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  TipoArv* atual = raiz->son;
  while (atual != NULL) {
    if (imprimir_caminho(atual, arquivo)) {
      return 1;
    }
    atual = atual->brother;
  }
  return 0;
}
int main() {
  TipoArv raiz;
  int n;
  char b[1025];
  char acao[3], s1[1025], s2[1025];
  scanf("%d", &n);
  scanf("%s", b);
  inicializa(&raiz);
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    scanf("%s", acao);
    if (strcmp(acao, "-a") == 0) {
      scanf("%s %s", s1, s2);

      TipoArv* arquivo = cria(s1);
      TipoArv* pasta = buscar(&raiz, s2);
      if (pasta != NULL) {
        insere(pasta, arquivo);
      }
    }
    else if (strcmp(acao, "-m") == 0) {
      scanf("%s %s", s1, s2);
      TipoArv* arquivo = buscar(&raiz, s1);
      TipoArv* nova_pasta = buscar(&raiz, s2);
      if (arquivo != NULL && nova_pasta != NULL) {
        remover(arquivo->dad, s1);
        insere(nova_pasta, arquivo);
      }
    }
    else if (strcmp(acao, "-r") == 0) {
      scanf("%s", s1);
      TipoArv* j = buscar(&raiz, s1);
      if (j != NULL) {
        remover(&raiz, s1);
      }
    }
  }
  if (imprimir_caminho(&raiz, b) == 0) {
    printf("File not found!\n");
  }
  else {
    imprimir_caminho(&raiz, b);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For all inputs, the output is being "File not found".

Comment: Run this in your debugger. If you don't know how to use your debugger, learn now. That's the most economical use of your time by a factor of at least 10.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part.

Comment: Also please fix the formatting so that there isn't empty lines all over the place.

Comment: It looks like you somehow replaced all the newlines in your file with two newlines when posting.  See if you can repair that damage.

Comment: @Yunnosch it's not about real files at all here.

Comment: You should not mix the tree with your problem. It just makes things worse. It is even stated in the description of the activity: _...a generic tree to represent the structure of files and folders..._. Also it seems hard to believe that `insere` with just 3 lines of code will do the trick. Consider the example of adding 8 folders under `root`. You must also write a function to display the tree contents, before anything. Also always test the return value of `scanf`. It is naive to just assume that something was _scanned_.